# How to increase limit in vf page using APEX:inputFIle to 100-150 MB

Tags: apex, visualforce

We have a requirement to upload file using vf page.
We used APEX:FileInput that is throwing us limit of 20 MB only.
Is there a way to upload file more than 20 MB using vf page ?

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation [apex:inputFile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.242.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputFile.htm) only accepts files up to 10 mb:

> Note: The maximum file size that can be uploaded via Visualforce is 10 MB.

If you use the [apex:includeLightning](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.242.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_includeLightning.htm) on your Visualforce page you can then use a Lightning Web Component with the [lightning-file-upload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-file-upload/documentation) component, which would allow you to upload files up to 2gb.

Alternatively, you could build your own file upload system on the Visualforce page by using the [Salesforce file API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm#inserting_a_contentversion).

Comment: I tried this approach, but popup with progress bar + done Button doesn't come. When we Selected a file, nothing happens.

Comment: @confusedcodey if you could edit your question to include the code you've used then we may be able to help you better

Comment: I tried this approach, but popup with progress bar + done Button doesn't come. When we Selected a file, nothing happens.

Comment: <apex:outputpanel id="uploadFilePopup" layout="block" style="display: none" styleClass="customPopup" >
--> <apex:commandButton value="X" title="Close the popup" onclick="closePopup()" styleClass="closeButton"/> </apex:outputpanel>

Comment: <template>
    <lightning-file-upload class="UploadDLC"
         label="Upload Reports to DLC"
            name="uploadFile"
         record-id={recordId}    
         accept={acceptedFormats}
         onuploadfinished={UploadReportsAttachment} 
                           multiple> 
 </lightning-file-upload>
</template>

Comment: @confusedcodey the code should be [added to your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/403233/edit), not to this answer

Comment: @confusedcodey that can't be the whole of the code. For one thing the JavaScript is missing. And please follow RubenDG's advice and edit your question to include the code.